# Is there a way to tell SQL Server to check the table for a duplicate before inserting each new row?

Tags: sql-server, insert, duplicates

I tried using the SQL below to insert values from one table, `importTable`, into another table, `POInvoicing`. It appears that the way this query below works is it checks the `POInvoicing` table for any possible duplicates from the `importTable` and for those entries that are not duplicates, it inserts them into the table. The end result is SQL inserting duplicates that already exist in `importTable`. Is there a way to tell SQL Server to check the table for a possible duplicate entry, if not, add the next row. Then check the table for a duplicate entry, if not, add the next row. I know this will be slower but speed isn't an issue.

```sql
INSERT INTO POInvoicing 
    (VendorID, InvoiceNo) 
SELECT dbo.importTable.VendorID,
       dbo.importTable.InvoiceNo
  FROM dbo.importTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VendorID,
                         InvoiceNo
                    FROM POInvoicing
                   WHERE POInvoicing.VendorID = dbo.importTable.VendorID AND
                         POInvoicing.InvoiceNo = dbo.importTable.InvoiceNo)
```

This isn't exactly the functionality I was hoping for. What I want is for the query to insert a row into the table and then check for "duplicates" before inserting the next row. What constitutes a duplicate in the `importTable` would be the combination of VendorID and InvoiceNo. There are about a dozen different columns in `importTable` and technically each row is distinct, so `DISTINCT` won't work here.

I can't simply remove duplicates from the `importTable` for a couple of reasons not relevant to the question above (though I can provide it if necessary), so that method is out.

Comment: FYI, using 3 part naming from columns is deprecated and could be removed in a future version of SQL Server. It's recommended you alias your tables and then qualify your columns with the table's alias.

Comment: So if you have two rows in `importTable` (say, `VendorID = 5, InvoiceNo = 10`) and they have two different values (or the same value) for `InvoiceDate`, how do you decide which one is not the duplicate?

Comment: @AaronBertrand What makes each row different in the `importTable` is miscellaneous data that the `POInvoicing` table doesn't care about and won't be added to the `POInvoicing` table. On the other hand, our `POInvoicingDetails` table does care about that extra data and will make use of it. I suppose I could have further reduced the query for simplicity's sake. In reality, there won't be two entries with VendorID = 5, InvoiceNo = 10, with two different EntryDate's.

Comment: You could use MERGE statement and only handle INSERT with the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET portion?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche I don't think `MERGE` is what's needed here (it will still return multiple rows for `NOT MATCHED`), and [I wouldn't recommend it generally even if it were](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't care (or refuse to tell us) how you want to decide between two rows with the same `VendorID` and `InvoiceNo` values, you can pick an arbitrary row like this:

```
;WITH NewRows AS
(
  SELECT VendorID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, /* ... other columns ... */
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VendorID, InvoiceNo ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM dbo.importTable AS i
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.POInvoicing AS p
                      WHERE p.VendorID = i.VendorID
                      AND p.InvoiceNo = i.InvoiceNo)
)
INSERT dbo.POInvoicing(VendorID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate /* , ... other columns ... */)
  SELECT VendorID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate /* , ... other columns */
  FROM NewRows
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you later decide there is a specific row you want in the case of duplicates, you can swap out `(SELECT NULL)` for something else. For example, to take the row with the latest invoice date:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY VendorID, InvoiceNo ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC)
```

Again, I wasn't asking questions here to be annoying, it was to help you get the solution you need. If you want SQL Server to pick between two duplicates, you can either tell it how to pick, or you'll have to accept arbitrary / non-deterministic results. You should not jump the fence for looping / cursors just because the first thing you tried didn't work the way you wanted it to.

Also [please always specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [use sensible table aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a **primary key constraint** or **unique key constraint** in your table to avoid duplicate data insertion.

Also use **distinct** keyword in your select query to avoid this.

Duplicate rows can also be eliminated by using **group by** or **row_number()** functions in SQL.

Using DISTINCT Keyword

```
 INSERT INTO POInvoicing 
 (VendorID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate) 
 SELECT DISTINCT dbo.importTable.VendorID,
   dbo.importTable.InvoiceNo,
   dbo.importTable.InvoiceDate 
  FROM dbo.importTable
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VendorID,
                     InvoiceNo
                FROM POInvoicing
               WHERE POInvoicing.VendorID = dbo.importTable.VendorID 
 AND
                     POInvoicing.InvoiceNo = dbo.importTable.InvoiceNo)
```

Try this **INNER JOIN**

```
 INSERT INTO POInvoicing 
 (VendorID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate) 
 SELECT dbo.importTable.VendorID,
   dbo.importTable.InvoiceNo,
   dbo.importTable.InvoiceDate 
  FROM dbo.importTable IM
  INNER JOIN POInvoicing S ON S.POInvoicing.VendorID <> 
  dbo.importTable.VendorID 
 AND
                     S.POInvoicing.InvoiceNo <> dbo.importTable.InvoiceN
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. I think I need to amend my post a bit. There are a number of columns in `importTable`, not just three. So technically, each row is distinct. I want to tell SQL that for the sake of this INSERT query, what makes something distinct is based only on the unique combination of `VendorID` and `InvoiceNo`.

Comment: Try this inner join query.I think this will help u --@JohnCoolidge

Comment: Share ur comments -- @John Coolidge

Comment: @JohnCoolidge If you have a combination of two columns that "makes something distinct" then you need to tell SQL Server which row you want when there are multiple. You may not care which row you get but SQL Server needs to break the tie somehow. Show us some actual data (with the same values for these two columns along with some realistic values for the other columns) and tell us which row you want to keep/insert and why. Without details we can't help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So, what I gather from this is, there's no way to make SQL Server check the entire table before inserting each individual row. Because that would suffice to tell SQL server that the next insert is a duplicate. I know that would be super slow, but for what I'm doing, the darn thing could take an hour and it wouldn't matter because this query is going to be running at night when nobody is accessing SQL Server.

Comment: @JohnCoolidge All you need to do really is explicitly define why one insert should happen before or after another. What is "the next insert" and why did it happen _after_ the previous one? SQL Server works best in sets - yes of course you could write a cursor that would loop through all the source rows and inserts them one at a time, and maybe that would take an hour, but why do that when - with a *slightly better definition of the problem* - you can write a set-based query that takes milliseconds?